# How to use multiple where conditions PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am trying to create a query using multiple WHERE conditions, both AND and NOT, and I am having trouble. Both conditions work separately, but not together. Most likely I've gotten the syntax wrong.

Here's the query

```
$getposts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE (category=".$_POST['category'].") AND (id NOT IN ( '" . implode($array, "', '") . "' )) ORDER BY popularity DESC") or die(mysql_query());
```

I've tried with and without parentheses, but with no change. As I say, both this query:

```
$getposts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE category=".$_POST['category']." ORDER BY popularity DESC") or die(mysql_query());
```

and this query:

```
$getposts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE id NOT IN ( '" . implode($array, "', '") . "' ) ORDER BY popularity DESC") or die(mysql_query());
```

work, just not when combined.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: do you realize your string string statement in mysql_query is broken?

Comment: edited to fix, just a typo here, not in the actual code.

Comment: post your query with the combined condition

Comment: @PrinceG it's the first one in the question

Comment: oh, sorry didn't see that, are you expecting the query to return all rows that meets both condition?

Comment: no worries. Yeah if possible

Comment: if that's the case, using `AND` is right. you should check if there are records that actually matches those condition when combined.

Comment: have had a look around, haven't managed to find anything

Comment: Your query looks fine. If it is returning no results then maybe there are no results. Reduce your list of IDs to just one ID that you know will be found in a matching row from the other query. Also, capture the result of your query in a variable. Then check if '$result === false' ( 3 equal signs). If it is false, then check 'mysql_error()' output. If not, capture 'mysql_num_rows($result)' in a variable and see if it === 0. Echo your query to the screen. Copy paste it into MySQL or phpMyAdmin and see if you get 0 results or an error there.